# How to wait for orientation change completely before changing scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to wait for screen change orientation completely before doing next task ?

```
IEnumerator ChangeOrientation()
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;

    // Fix background not completely rotate on unpacking story
    yield return Timing.WaitUntilTrue(() => Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft);

    bool unpack = storyData.sceneBundleName.Length > 0; //If we have loaded a scene bundle
    StoryManager.Instance.StartStory(this, unpack);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have never tried it, but - reading on the [forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/device-screen-rotation-event.118638/) - it seems that `OnRectTransformDimensionsChange()` does the trick.

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.OnRectTransformDimensionsChange.html) the (short) documentation.

Comment: Ya i heard about it, but does it mean I need to add RectTransform component on my gameObject right? because mine is normal transform

Comment: It seems so. By the way, you could create a "utility" object and attach a RectTransform just to it. At that point, set the listener to this one. I think it could worth a try, do you agree?

Comment: Of course could not agree more, Just now I use temporary fix by just put WaitForSeconds(0.3f) and no graphic glitch at least. So for now I will stick on it first. Will try when had some time. Great @Andrea

Comment: @TengkuFathullah I thought about waiting too but this answer is more reliable than waiting for x seconds. Some devices may take one second to do that and your game code will fail.

Comment: @Programmer Thats I am waiting for, to wait for issue then proceed with better method, I already have guts feeling and you said the same thing. I Guess I will use this new method.

Comment: If you are doing the test and waiting for an issue with one device,that's unrealistic and you are wasting your time. There are hundreds of Android devices out there and some of these have different behavior.